# Executing suspend function inside Iterable.sortedBy

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have this code:

```
interface Film {

  suspend fun total(): Int

}

suspend fun getFilms() : List<Film> {
  return films.sortedBy { it.total() }
}
```

But I get an error because I'm calling `Film::total` method inside non-suspension function (`sortedBy` selector). How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
suspend fun getFilms(): List<Film> {
    return films
        .map { it to it.total() }
        .sortedBy { it.second }
        .map { it.first }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is just a warning, anyways you can force it to run using `runBlocking`

```
suspend fun getFilms() : List<Film> {
    val films = arrayListOf<Film>()
    return films.sortedBy { runBlocking {  it.total() } }
}
```

Comment: It's not a warning it's an error ("Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body") due to how Coroutines work. I cannot figure out how using runBlocking could be of help other that make the code compile. That scope should be used for testing purposes/in main.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap @IR42's answer in an extension function to make code a bit more readable if you use this in multiple places.

```
suspend inline fun <T, R : Comparable<R>> Iterable<T>.sortedBySuspending(
    crossinline selector: suspend (T) -> R?
): List<T> = this
    .map { it to selector(it) }
    .sortedBy { it.second }
    .map { it.first }
```

Answer (score -1):

The error states it clearly *"Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body"*. You are invoking *total()* from within *sortedBy* thus the error.
You should give more context in order for me to be able to provide a more accurate answer. Having such little context you can remove the *suspend* from *total()* to let the code compile. Anyway just try this:

```
suspend fun getFilms() = films.sortedBy { it.total() }
```

If you cannot change the interface what about something like that:

```
data class MyFilm(val total: Int) : Film {
    override suspend fun total(): Int = total 
}

suspend fun getFilms(): List<Film> = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
   films.sortedBy { it.total }     
}
```

Comment: Thank yout but this shouldn't be an answer but a comment.

Comment: @Héctor not exactly. Just removing the suspend modifier answers your question. Also note that the accepted answer is highly inefficient (I've edited the answer)

Comment: Well, deleting all my code would solve my problem as well, but that's not an answer either. I have `suspend` modifier because I need it, so removing it it's not an option.

Comment: How does your proposal differs from my code? (without removing suspend from `total` method)

Comment: @Héctor I'm trying to understand your problem just try to be respectful please. 
That method IMO has little sense with the susp. modifier (instead of being sarcastic you could try to explain why it is suspendable for example). Coming to the accepted answer ( "awesome" you said) it sure compiles, but it has a plain ridiculous complexity. To sort a list you are mapping (aka allocating a new list of pairs), sorting (another new list) and then mapping (new list) to get the sorted list. If you are in Android try it on a low-end emulator with a huge amount of films and you will realize what I mean.

Comment: @Héctor I re-edited my answer just in case you cannot change the interface definition

Comment: I'm sorry for being sarcastic. You're right, I will explain. I'm aware `total()` method being suspend is a little weird, but it's how it is designed: it queries to a database, so it needs to be suspend. I'm in a backend environment. At this moment, I'm not worried about resources, but of course, I will accept another answer that compiles and works better in terms of performance than the accepted one. Your answer doesn't compile, btw, `withContext` has nothing to do there.

Comment: Ok, no worries :) I suppose that the list of films is returned by the lib you use to talk with the database. What lib and framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using Vert.x with MongoClient and mongodb database

Comment: @Héctor I don't know Vert.x (I work with Spring), but I just do a little search and I came across this: https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-lang-kotlin-coroutines/kotlin/#_introduction, from what I'm seeing Vert.x has its own dispatcher to execute suspend functions. Could you please take a look at this example: https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-lang-kotlin-coroutines/kotlin/#_running_a_coroutine_from_a_vert_x_context? Let me know if that helps

Comment: It doesn't change anything, `sortedBy` takes a cross-inline lambda, which will not make the context available inside.

Comment: IMO the problem is not sortedBy per se but I 
still don't get why that list of films cannot come ordered from the database in the first place